# jQuery advanced hover and fadeIn function

Tags: jquery, hover, fadein, fadeout

Is it possible that I was overworked and looking for a problem that is quite primitive:)
I have the following HTML code:

```
<h1 class="cloud"><a>bla</a></h1>
<div class="caption">
 <img ...../> etc
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".cloud").hover(function() {
    var pos = $(this);
    var position = pos.position();
    $(this).next().css({ 'top' : position.top+45});
    $(this).next().css({ 'left' : position.left+12});
    $(this).next().slideDown("slow");
  } , function() {
    $(this).next().slideUp("slow");
});
```

And I needed to make the DIV not fadeOut when mouse on it. So after moving to H1 fadeOut be made when the mouse move to the DIV that will stay open when the mouse moves away (except H1) so that it fadeIn.

Comment: Can you please translate your title?

Comment: Srry :) jQuery hover, and more complex functions fadeIn

Comment: It is jQuery advanced hover and fadeIn function :) it is in czech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe is not exactly what you're looking for but if you wrap your html above around a div you can handle it.
here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/vmHaf/1/

hope that helps

Comment: srry, I tried it on my code and the error is somewhere. In Firebug : position is null. http://jsfiddle.net/hn4B3/4/

Comment: you changed you html, look for h2 instead of h1. updated: http://jsfiddle.net/hn4B3/5/ . you have to refine your css to avoid freaky behavior i guess